# Django 1.8 migration: any way to get data from database table that no longer has a model?

Tags: django, django-migrations, django-database

I'm trying to rename a model and I would like to write the migration in the way that it doesn't depend on the old name still present while it being applied. Can I somehow get data from a database table that no longer has a model in my migration code?

Details:
I have a `Region` model that I want to move into a more generic `GeoObject` model and remove from the `models.py`. If I write my migration code that creates `GeoObjects` from existing `Regions` with `from models import Region` I'll have to keep `Region` model until my main database will migrate. But I'd like to write a migration so that it doesn't depend on `Region` model being present, just check that the database table exists and use it. Is it possible to do it using Django instruments, without depending on a specific database type if possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can.

But first of all, you really shouldn't import any model inside migration.

Take look at [`RunPython`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/migration-operations/#runpython) operation, that will allow you to run any python code inside your migration. `RunPython` will pass to your function 2 parameters: `apps` and `schema_editor`. First parameter contains structure of your models at stage of applying that migration, so if actual removing of model is later on that migration, you can still access that model using `apps` passed into function.

Let's say your model looked like this:

```
class SomeModel(models.Model):
    some_field = models.CharField(max_length=32)
```

Now you're deleting that model, automatically created migration will contain:

```
class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    dependencies = [
        ('yourapp', '0001_initial'), # or any other dependencies
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.DeleteModel(
            name='Main',
        ),
    ]
```

You can modify that migration by injecting RunPython just above DeleteModel operation:

```
    operations = [
        migrations.RunPython(
            move_data_to_other_model,
            move_data_back, # for backwards migration - if you won't ever want to undo this migration, just don't pass that function at all
        ),
        migrations.DeleteModel(
            name='SomeModel',
        ),
    ]
```

and creating 2 functions before Migration class:

```
def move_data_to_other_model(apps, schema_editor):
    SomeModel = apps.get_model('yourapp', 'SomeModel')

    for something in SomeModel.objects.all():
        # do your data migration here
        o = OtherModel.objects.get(condition=True)
        o.other_field = something.some_field

def move_data_back(apps, schema_editor):
    SomeModel = apps.get_model('yourapp', 'SomeModel')

    for something in OtherModel.objects.all():
        # move back your data here
        SomeModel(
            some_field=something.other_field,
        ).save()
```

It doesn't matter that your model is no longer defined in models.py, django can rebuild that model based on migration history. But remember: save method from your models (and other customized methods) won't be called in migrations. Also any pre_save or post_save signals won't be triggered.

Comment: Thanks, appreciate the effort, but how could I write code that creates new instances inside a migration? Yes, I'm already using `RunPython` and I don't even know any other way, is there one? Anyway, the problem is that I don't yet know how to access database table that doesn't have a model. I already removed the model from `models.py`. I'll re-check docs by the link, thanks.

Comment: `apps` passed into your function doesn't depend on your models.py. It depends on migration history. That models state is built by migration operations that have been already executed, so if operation that removes your model from database is later on migrations, that model will be still available using `apps`. See updated answer.

Comment: Perfect. Thanks a lot.